# XCOPY Dos Command copy from child folder

Tags: c++, command, dos, xcopy

I have a C++ Program that uses the XCOPY DOS command to copy some files.

```
string command = "xcopy " + source + " " + dest;
const char * cmd = command.c_str();
system(cmd);
```

My problem is that this only works when the source file is in the same folder as the EXE. I want to be able to copy X from a child folder.

Does anybody know how i can copy from a source folder without providing the full path (c:\blahh\blahh)? 
As:
    `xcopy childFolder/filename newname` 
does not work.

I am currently using:
`xcopy copy.h h.h` However does not work for child folders.

Thanks

Comment: try using the other slash. Also try providing '.' for current directory: `xcopy .\some_folder\temp.txt copy_of_temp.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

izomorphius has almost the complete answer in his comment - you should use a back slash. The other issue is you must escape the folder delimiters:

```
string source = "childfolder\\filename"
```